# 500 internal error on laravel app on aws ec2

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to deploy laravel app on aws instance  .both server & mysql are in the same db.db shows connected  .When I hit aws public ip/controllername it gives internal error  .In local environment it was working fine. here is my apache virtual host conf

```
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/marine-cargo-module/public
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 AllowOverride 
All Require all granted
```

I also have .htaccess file on the laravelapp/public folder like below

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes RewriteEngine On

Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} . RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$ RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

kindly help me to get the application working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `writtable` permission to `storage` & `bootstrap` folder.

Check the appache error logs for more details.

Comment: Hopefully you have already installed the composer dependancies. Let me know if you stil facing the issue.